# Dynamically added Raddocks Optimization?

Tags: telerik

We have a optimization problem regarding rad dock controls. The requirement of project is such that we are creating dynamic raddocks on the fly and adding it to a raddockzone, then we are saving the raddock "type" etc in a mssql db. We also have a collector window/raddockzone in which we have build a functionality where we can drag a dock and save it in collector. As with the first raddockzone we are adding the dock in collector on the fly. Now while adding a dock or moving it to another raddockzones it takes sometime. Our client is comparing it with the example of the demo link : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/content/defaultcs.aspx

Following is our code snippet to add dock on the fly:

```
private RadDockNew CreateRadDock()
{


    //string[] allowedZones = { "RDZCollector", "RadDockZone2" };
    int width = Convert.ToInt32((hdnWidth.Value == "") ? "520" : hdnWidth.Value);
    RadDockNew dock = new RadDockNew();
    dock.DockMode = DockMode.Docked;
    dock.UniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "a");
    dock.ID = string.Format("RadDock{0}", dock.UniqueName);
    //dock.Title = dock.UniqueName.Substring(dock.UniqueName.Length - 3);
    dock.Width = Unit.Pixel(width);
    dock.CssClass = "RadDockZoneMain";
    //dock.AllowedZones = allowedZones;
    dock.Style.Add("min-height", "290px");
    dock.OnClientDockPositionChanged = "DropInCollector";
    //dock.EnableViewState = false;
    DockCommand cmd = new DockCommand();
    cmd.Name = "Setting";
    cmd.Text = "Setting";
    cmd.OnClientCommand = "showSettings";
    dock.Commands.Add(cmd);
    DockCommand dc = new DockCommand();
    dc.Text = "Trash";
    dc.Name = "Trash";
    dc.OnClientCommand = "CloseDock";
    dc.CssClass = "rdClose";
    dc.AutoPostBack = true;
    dock.Commands.Add(dc);
    DockToggleCommand cmd2 = new DockToggleCommand();
    cmd2.CssClass = "rdCollapse";
    cmd2.AlternateCssClass = "rdexpand";
    cmd2.OnClientCommand = "ChangeImage";


    //DockCommand collapse = new DockCommand();
    //collapse.Text = "Collapse/Expand";
    //collapse.Name = "Collapse/Expand";
    //collapse.OnClientCommand = "CollapseDock";
    //collapse.CssClass = "rdCollapse";
    dock.Commands.Add(cmd2);
    return dock;
}
```

Please tell if there is any way to optimize / make it faster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I examined the attached code sample and I think that it is correct. My suggestions are to check if the problem persists if you use other storage medium, instead of a database or if there are client script errors on the page, containing the RadDocks.

As the setup of your project seems to be similar to the one, implemented in the [My Portal](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/myportal/defaultcs.aspx) demo, I would recommend using the example in the Code Library article [Saving State of Dynamically Created RadDocks in DataBase using Hidden UpdatePanel](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/docking/saving-state-of-dynamically-created-raddocks-in-database-using-hidden-updatepanel.aspx) as a reference.